# how global variable differs from class variable, are they the same?

Tags: c++, class, variables, namespaces, global

Given that a variable declared outside a function is a global variable.

```
//sample.cpp
int g = 0;
namespace foo 
{
    int x = 5;
    class bar
    {
        int y = 7;
        /** rest of the bar class **/
    }
    /** rest of the bar namespace **/
}
```

I understand that g is a global variable.
My question is:
is x a global variable?
is y a global variable?
in other words: are variables declared(defined in my example) in class and namespace global variables aswell?

added after edit >> whole text that follows.

changed sample.cpp to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int g;
int g2 = 2;
namespace foo 
{
    extern int x = 5;
    extern int x2; //accessing x2 will lead to an error.
    class bar
    {
      public:
        int foo::bar::y; //declaring y with a value will lead to an error.
        /** rest of the bar class **/
    };
    /** rest of the bar namespace **/
}

int main()
{

}
```

As Jon suggested I tried some things out and come to the following assumptions:

- g is a global variable and is initialized with 0 and is initialized before main().
- x is a namespace variable and must be given a declaration and is initialized before main().
- y is a class variable which can not be given a declaration and is not initialized before main() and must be initialized by i.e. a constructor.
- the only global variable is g i guess, since all global int-variables are initialized with the value 0, which is not the case for x and y.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: you can't define var out side of the class scope .

Comment: you will get the error namespace doesn't contain fields or methods directly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer. x is. y isn't.

x is global insofar as it can be accessed from anywhere in your program *but* you must fully qualify it's name as foo.x. To access it from another file you would normally have to include an extern statement: **extern int foo.x** which, in effect, tells the compiler 'there is an int variable called foo.x somewhere in this program, you just haven't seen it yet'. The reference will be resolved at link time.

y is a member variable of the class bar. For each instance of bar there is y contained in that object.

Comment: you can't define var out side of the class  you will get compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

First we come on global var and local var

Global var is accessible in any of method or function locally or globally while local var is limited to its surrounding or simply can't be called in different method it is accessible inside of the method.

We can't declare var out side of the class both of the variables should be initialized in the class scope accessible in any of the method or function in the class so you can say that these are the Global var.

Hope this will help you to understand the local and the global var.